# Why offsetof implementations strangely differs on C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, offsetof

I opened `stddef.h` and saw this:

```
#if defined _MSC_VER && !defined _CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
    #else
        #define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&(((s*)0)->m))
    #endif
#else
    #define offsetof(s,m) __builtin_offsetof(s,m)
#endif
```

In branch of `__cplusplus` (In case of C++ compiler) there is very strange implementation, I think it's redundant. Else branch (case of C compiler) has simpler calculation of field offset. And I tested it, it works. For what used this strange casts and type qualifiers in first case?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think I disagree with your statement. C++ casts are *safer* than C cast. But: C style cast does have compile-time checks: you can't cast between unrelated classes for instance. And while C++ casts have more compile-time checks, it still lets you do invalid things: you can for instance reinterpret_cast between int and float: `int a = 24; float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&a);` this compiles without any errors

Comment: @bolov That's still a cast between pointers, though. But ``reinterpret_cast`` is safer than a C-style cast because the latter will do any of that which ``static_cast``, ``reinterpret_cast`` and ``const_cast`` do, or even some combination of one of the former with the latter (e.g. ``static_cast`` plus ``const_cast``).

Comment: By the way, if user code contained a null pointer dereference, it would be undefined behavior. However, this is in a platform header, and the platform devs have special rights…

Comment: @ArneVogel yes, I've said that C++ casts is safer than C cast

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`operator &` can be overloaded for the type of `m`, so `&((s*)0)->m)` would call that `operator &` instead of taking `m`'s address.

And `const volatile` is there in the `reinterpret_cast`'s type so that it works even when `m` is `const` and/or `volatile`.

Note that in C++11, there is `std::addressof(x)` which always takes the address of `x` regardless of `operator &` overloads. It's likely to be implemented in a similar fashion to what you see in the question.

Comment: Note that C++11 and later have [`std::addressof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) to handle the `operator&` issue. `offsetof()` could be written as `#define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)std::addressof(((s*)0)->m))`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. I was thinking about it, but didn't mention it in the end. Did now.